# How can you specify where Maven puts the dependent JARs?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have configured my POM to include the Maven-Surefire plugin, as well as a dependency to a repository with some Selenium stuff.

After running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, my project now has 100 jars, including the Jetty, Spring, and Selenium jars, *all at the root of the project*.

The project builds and runs fine, but how can I put the jars into a directory so it doesn't look so bad?  Is this something I can configure in the POM?

Comment: Why do you have Spring in there? Have you given a dependency?

Comment: Not sure why any of the jars were listed (including the Spring ones).  The dependency is there for sure, I am using Spring in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the maven eclipse plugin ("mvn eclipse:eclipse"), you could use maven eclipse integration plugin ([m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)), all your jars will stay in the local repository.

Comment: I'd say "should" rather than "could". Note however that you cannot use the project built by the maven eclipse plugin with m2eclipse, you have to start again from scratch. It will be done automatically for you by m2eclipse, though.

Comment: Thanks Tristan, I am using SpringSource Tool Suite which I believe comes loaded with m2eclipse.  But you are right, I think I imported the project incorrectly.